# Is the "loading" template special in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I see that the following template is rendered if loading the model takes a long time:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="loading">
    <h1>Loading</h1>
  </script>
```

The `Route` must be defined:

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

But the router needs no configuration for this to be active. I think this is ember-related behavior (although it could also be handlebars-related, but I do not think so).

- Are there other special template names?
- Where is this magic documented? (not possible to find it in the [Ember documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/the-application-template/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already noticed the router needs no definition for the `LoadingRoute` since it's somewhat special. The `LoadingRoute` will be looked up by ember, and if it's find one it is used for exact the expected behavior.

Have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ixazeb/2/edit) for an simulated loading example.

> Are there other special template names?

Yes, there is also a special route called `FailureRoute` which can be used to handle  errors globally.

> Where is this magic documented? (not possible to find it in the Ember documentation)

As for some documentation on this please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589). Some of the changes where introduced not long ago, so documentation is somewhat sparse.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! So it is indeed an ember feature, and not yet documented. It would be good if this internal magic was described in the documentation. The names are self-explanatory, but the details are not completely clear. For example: how long must the update of the model take for the `loading` template to be shown? Is it always shown (but not really visible, because it happens so quickly)? This must be in ember code somewhere ...

Comment: As far I know the `LoadingRoute` is always displayed, but if the request comes back very quick there is a possibility that it's not shown at all, or better it is shown so quickly that it can't be seen. As for the lack of documentation, you are right, this stuff should be well documented in the official docs, maybe I'll propose a PR for this.